# how to access based row based on condition with grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, slice

I am new to Python and I want to access some rows for an already grouped dataframe (used groupby).

However, I am unable to select the row I want and would like your help.

The code I used for groupby shown below:

```
language_conversion = house_ads.groupby(['date_served','language_preferred']).agg({'user_id':'nunique',
                                                                                   'converted':'sum'})
language_conversion
```

Result shows:
[image]

For example, I want to access the number of Spanish-speaking users who received house ads using:

`language_conversion[('user_id','Spanish')]`

gives me KeyError('user_id','Spanish')

This is the same when I try to create a new column, which gives me the same error.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `user_id` is a column and `language_preferred` is the second level of a multiindex. You can't access data in this dataframe like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,
`language_conversion.loc[(slice(None), 'Arabic'), 'user_id']`

You can see the indices(in this case tuples of length 2) using `language_conversion.index`

Comment: remove the parenthesis in the end no required and date he didn't mention so you might need to consider case where he needs all dates.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it solved my problem

Comment: you have just rewrote my answer after i mentioned ur mistakes, that isn't  a bad thing you could have come up with another solution so that info might be more than redundant anyways great :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use this

```
language_conversion.loc[(slice(None),'Spanish'), 'user_id']
```

slice(None) here includes all rows in date index.

if you have one particular date in mind just replace slice(None) with that specific date.

the error you are getting is because u accessed columns before indexes which is not correct way of doing it follow the link to learn more [indexing](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-data-in-a-multiindex-dataframe-in-pandas-569e8767201d)

Comment: thanks for the answer, it solved my problem